# How to get User-Specific URL Field to show in Lightning Community Home Page?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community

I'm building a Partner Community in Lightning, and we have a user-specific link that I would like to get on the home page.

Simple enough to do in SalesForce Classic, just create a VF page that references the field {{user.field__c}} and then create a home page component to show that VF page.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get this in Lightning, and feel like I'm running around in circles looking at Dev Console documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Lightning components do not pick up context information automatically. You need to build it in. This page should guide you through the process: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/11/building-context-aware-lightning-components.html

has:recordID can be used to get the record ID of the page the user is in, for example.